# Unexporting remote objects passed as arguments in remote method call

Tags: java, rmi

I was wondering if there's a need to explicitly unexport a remote object passed as a parameter in a remote method call when they don't need to exist anymore. For example: I've an online game, when the client asks the GameServer(binded in a RMI registry) for a game the server returns to the client a GameHandler as a remote object. When the game is over and the GameHandler has no need to be active anymore, do I have to call `UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(this, false);`? I'm doing it but sometimes I get a `NoSuchObjectException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be unexported automatically via DGC and local GC when there are no remote or local references. If you want to know when DGC has kicked in, implement the `Unreferenced` interface.